# Android - Reload SQLiteDatabase after download from server

Tags: java, android, sqlite, reload

I have a DatabaseHelper.java (extends SQLiteOpenHelper) which I use to create and migrate my database. Then, for each table in the database I'm using a custom ContentProvider, each having it's own reference to the database (SQLiteDatabase) (this may be a terrible setup, I'm new to java :) ). Users can insert, update, delete, etc from the database. They can also import and replace this database with another .sqlite file completely. This is all working great.

My question is, once a database is imported and replaces the previous database, how do I refresh the data being displayed? The only obvious way I've found is to reset the application, but clearly that's not ideal. In objective-c I can fire a global notification and any instantiated object listening for that notification will perform an action of my choosing. I need something like this... Unless there is a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

I want to note that I achieved the 'refresh' of the database by calling:

```
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Table1Provider.CONTENT_URI, null);
        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(Table2Provider.CONTENT_URI, null);
```

But I'm still curious about whether this setup is ideal. I know there are a lot of opinions about how things should be setup, so any thoughts are welcome.